# Is there a way to run Guild Wars in windowed fullscreen (borderless) mode?

Tags: guild-wars

I'm looking for a way to run Guild Wars in a borderless fullscreen window (like recent Valve games allow), since running it windowed makes it play much nicer with a second monitor, but I'd rather not waste screen space on a titlebar.

I've tried the autohotkey script suggested in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17306/how-to-force-maximized-fullscreen-mode-in-any-game), but it doesn't work for Guild Wars, which I'm guessing needs some extra help.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `this question` is missing a link, I think?

Comment: Oh, oops. Sorry about that. Fixed.

Comment: If all else fails, you could run it fullscreen on a VM on one screen and do other stuff on the other screen, outside the VM :)

Comment: @Aerus I suppose, although that seems pretty extreme. And resource hungry. And also requires another windows key for the VM. Probably not worth it just to get rid of window decorations.

Comment: Voting to leave open. Not having an answer is *not* a reason to close a question. Editing in "It seems like this may unfortunately not be possible." is also bad practice. You can instead post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not seem to be possible in Guild Wars 1.

Answer (score 0):

[ShiftWindow](http://www.grismar.net/shiftwindow/) should give you the desired effect. It's used by a lot of livestreamers on sites that require windowed streaming so they can play "fullscreen."

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't do it. Triggering the rule causes Guild Wars to resize momentarily, then it jumps back to being a fullscreen window with visible decoration.

Comment: Update: It's possible to shift the window so the decorations are off the screen on the top, but it doesn't seem to allow the window to be resized larger vertically to compensate. Same goes for horizontal adjustments.

Comment: Update: This might be a windows 7 issue?

Comment: @Zxaos I don't think so. The game just reacts to the windows messages for resizing and reverts them if it does not fit the parameters the developers wanted for the game window.