# Change default display of a game (Assassin's Creed 2)

Tags: windows-7, assassins-creed-2

No sure if this is a general Windows 7 question or particular to Assassin's Creed 2.

How do I change the display adapter that the game starts in?

EDIT:
Without changing the whole "Main Display" setting of Windows

Comment: When you say "display adapter" do you mean "which monitor" or "which GPU" or what?

Comment: I have one monitor connected to my onboard adapter (monitor A), and another connected to a PCIe NVidia card (monitor B). Currently, it launches on monitor A (configured as the "Main Display" in Windows for other reasons). I want the game to run on monitor B.

Comment: There's no good way to force full screen hardware accelerated rendering onto a non-primary GPU, I'm afraid.  There are some kludgy ones, but they don't work in all situations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I tell Steam which monitor to open a game on?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28525/can-i-tell-steam-which-monitor-to-open-a-game-on)