# Change output to second monitor?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In the original version of Skyrim there was an [ini setting](http://wiki.step-project.com/Guide:Skyrim_INI/Display#iAdapter) that could be used to change the output monitor. This doesn't seem to work with the special edition. Is there a configuration I can set for the game to output to the second monitor?

I'm aware I can change the monitor configuration in Windows, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Strange that this functionality breaks between the OG and SE editions. I'll look into it.

Comment: I take it you don't want to run the game in Windowed mode, which would allow you to move the game wherever you please?

Comment: There's also the possibility of using Steam's "Big Picture" mode, which may allow you to choose which display to play the game on, although I'd have to test it.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Yes I would prefer not to use Windowed mode. I was not aware Big Picture mode had this functionality, although [according to comments here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/85161/86920) it is just a wrap-around for changing the Windows monitor configuration which while not ideal, may be the only solution. I will fiddle with it when I get home from work.

Comment: As will I, I'll give things a shot and get back to you with anything I find! :)

Comment: Okay Fr33dan, bad news; Steam Big Picture won't work on a second monitor, it claims games can't be played on a secondary display, only the primary. Unfortunately, I'm out of ideas. :\