# Walking Dead Fullscreen Second Monitor

Tags: steam, monitor, the-walking-dead-season-one

How would I go about moving TWD to my second monitor (TV)?

**What does not work:**

- Win + Shift + Right/Left (It just makes the second monitor white and displays the game on the first one)
- A program that forces fullscreen windowed (Same as Win Shift Left/Right)

**What I do not want to do:**

- Switch my primary monitor

1st monitor 1080p 16:9 Dell
2nd monitor 1080p 16:9 Generic TV

The game is running from Steam.  If anyone could help me I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Are your screens configured in extended mode?  (Use win + p to select mode). Can you drag a window of another program (a web browser for example) to the second screen?

Comment: Yes I can, and Win + Shift + Right/Left works for everything else.

Comment: Can you set the config of TWD to windowed mode non-full screen on monitor 1, drag it to monitor 2, then set the config to windowed full screen?

Comment: Nope, that does not work!

Comment: What happens?   White screen?

Comment: Yes. And the game stays on the same screen. The other one just whites out.

Comment: That sucks.  There are lots of reports in forums with 2 monitor problems. Your only solution might be to set the TV as primary monitor when playing.  It might be a limitation of the game's design.

Comment: That majes me sad but ok.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I choose which monitor a game starts on?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/113417/how-can-i-choose-which-monitor-a-game-starts-on)