# How to prevent a(n old) fullscreen game from moving windows to the secondary screen?

Tags: windows, monitor

When I play some older fullscreen games (e.g. Diablo 2 or Rollercoaster Tycoon 3), their switching the primary monitor (left one) to a lower resolution somehow causes all open and maximized windows to be moved to the secondary monitor (on the right), where the will remain even after closing the game. How can this be prevented?

I've already found some related questions but they differ:

- [How to move a fullscreen game to the second monitor?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/138531/88) - I'm perfectly fine with playing on my primary monitor
- [Windows on secondary monitor gets moved when resolution changes](https://superuser.com/q/1046438/35237) - Windows on the secondary monitor stay fine
- [Prevent second monitor to "move" while in fullscreen games](https://superuser.com/q/420924/35237) - same I guess, though an implication of [the accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/420927/35237) is that the (low) resolution of the primary monitor might be to blame. I suspect the low resolution causes enough of the maximized windows to actually have their coordinates on the secondary monitor or such?
- [Dual Monitors Switching While Running Full-Screen Game?](https://superuser.com/q/258902/35237) - that's probably a related problem which I'd like to fix later as well, but the solution might be independent

Since the games are old enough a circumvention would be running them in a VM with video scaling to my native resolution, but that's not ideal. I do however wonder if there exists a tool which can create a "virtual" kind of monitor into which the game is restricted but which is then displayed scaled up without requiring as many resources as a full VM.

Comment: See if `DxWnd` would work?

Comment: I experience this too with games - old and new.  I think I remember reading once that Windows does a poor job at managing windows when screen resolutions change due to some app changing it, and I think having dual monitors (as I do) compounds the issue as well.

Comment: @timmyJim That's my experience as well, especially on pre-win7 games. If I had to hazard a guess I'd say that before that there wasn't a good unifying API to handle resolution changes.