# How can I move Morrowind in windowed mode on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

I have a widescreen display so Morrowind looks skewed in fullscreen mode.

However, If I start it in windowed mode, *it is drawn slightly off screen*, with the top being above the boundary of my screen.

Since the game also steals the keyboard and mouse from the OS, I can't seem to move it nywhere. I already searched for some methods of moving an off-screen window, [this for example](https://superuser.com/a/53590), but none work for this reason.

Answer (score 1):

There's this program called [ShiftWindow](http://grismar.net/shiftwindow/) that I use to move windowed games on my screens when the normal ways do not work. I've written a [more detailed answer about it already](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/129056/51318), but the basic idea is that you select the program, set the coordinates (or select target display) and hit "Trigger it". It has worked fine for me in Windows 8 and I see no reason why it wouldn't work in 7.