# Is it possible to play Civ 6 or BE on a Secondary Monitor?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth, civilization-6

I am running a dual monitor setup with the Primary Monitor on the right.

In Windows, pressing <kbd>[image]</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> (or <kbd>→</kbd>) will attempt to move the current application to the appropriate monitor.

When I do this with Civ VI, the game moves to the Secondary monitor just fine... but then I am unable to navigate menus or interact with the game in any way. Moving the game back to the Primary monitor (via the same keyboard shortcut) fixes these issues.

What is going wrong here? I'd like to run Civ VI on a secondary monitor without completing retooling my Windows display settings. (I ran into an identical issue the last time I played Civ: BE, so I'm not sure if it's something specific to those games, something specific to Firaxis games, or an unlikely coincidence)

Comment: What video mode are you in borderless window?

Comment: @Mike Yup. Borderless Window.

Comment: I have had the same problem I hope this thread gets more attention!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I tell Steam which monitor to open a game on?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28525/can-i-tell-steam-which-monitor-to-open-a-game-on)

Comment: @Valamas Don't think so - this is specific to these two games. Every other steam game works fine.

Comment: Same problem here, in both borderless and non-borderless windowed mode. I can drag the map, but it seems like the area I clicked is off by a few inches (screen space). Can't interact with menus at all unless I use hotkeys. Tried clicking off to the side of the menus buttons to see if the issue was just that all clicks were off by a certain X amount, but that didn't seem to work. Very weird.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. Doesn't matter if it's bordered window or borderless. Only way I've found to get around this is to change my primary monitor which is a real pain in the ass.

Comment: I am having the same problem too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Steam then you can use Steam's Big Picture mode. Go to View > Big Picture Mode. Then go to Settings > Resolution > Target Monitor and select the monitor you want to use. It will automatically move and adjust itself to the selected monitor. Now if you launch the game from Steam it will be properly adjusted to the selected monitor. You may need to switch the game's graphics settings to Borderless Window mode in order for it to be full screen. Also, if the text becomes too small then make sure you tick the UI Upscaling box in the game's graphics options.

If you did not purchase the game through Steam you can still launch it using Steam by adding it as a short-cut to your Steam games library.  Hope this helps

Comment: Hmmm, I have no Target Monitor option in Resolution despite running a second monitor...

Answer (score 0):

The solution with the Big Picture Mode appears to work, but what it in fact does is change the primary screen, which you could also do in Display Settings. This is not a real solution because it messes up your desktop.

I noticed that the game screen does respond if it is on a secondary screen to the right of the primary one, but not if the secondary screen is on the left.

It is actually quite silly, but also quite annoying.

Comment: @Vemonus This part does: *"the game screen does respond if it is on a secondary screen to the right of the primary one, but not if the secondary screen is on the left."*

Comment: @Robotnik ah I was reading it as explaining what the other answer does, not as its own answer.