# Is there a difference between running games in Windowed or Fullscreen mode?

Tags: pc, graphics-card

Does playing game when it's windowed increase performance? Decrease it?

Does the same also hold true to fullscreen mode? I've always thought that playing on Fullscreen meant a higher fps boost, but I never confirmed this.

Is there a difference between the two, and if so, what are they?

Comment: The answer is: It depends on the game and how it's implemented. Is there a specific game you had in mind?

Comment: I feel there might be a good question in here, as games are pretty unique to how they behave when in fullscreen.  That said, it's also something fairly easily testable, and an effort should have been prior to asking.

Comment: There are too many variables to give a solid 100% answer. It really depends a lot on specific hardware setups, and can vary game by game.

Comment: In general, what's the effect on performance? I've heard that if you play on Windowed, the computer has to render the Desktop of your computer, so it takes up more RAM, thus decreasing performance, but I'm not an expert on the subject nor have I actually seen any change

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Depends on the resolution you play at. If your game resolution is your desktop resolution, then fullscreen is likely to be slightly faster than windowed mode in all scenarios, for the reasons enumerated by [Philipp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/107071/23).

Honestly, however, on my dated hardware I take a much greater performance hit by running games at desktop resolution than I do by playing at a lower resolution through the window manager. If your desktop resolution is not your game resolution, by all means do play in windowed mode.

Fullscreen mode at non-native resolution means that instead of shifting graphics output to a rectangle on the screen (something relatively fast), your computer instead has to scale the picture from the game resolution to your native resolution with bicubic filtering or better (expensive!).

Even if it is your monitor itself that does the heavy lifting, or if you disabled hardware scaling at higher resolutions (in which case you still have to translate pixel coordinates), you will get *terrible* performance and occasionally crashes whenever you Alt-Tab from and to the game.

Finally, not all operative systems allow you to skip the screen compositing system altogether. A notable exception is certainly Ubuntu (which can draw notifyOSD notifications on top of games); I don't know how Macs work here.

So, if getting every single last drop of framerate is your priority here, ***only* play in fullscreen mode:**

- If you're using Windows (or Mac?), *and*
- If you're playing at your screen's native resolution, *and*
- If you *can't* get a speedup by playing at lower resolutions in a window, *and*
- If your desktop is set at your screen's native resolution.

Comment: Nice, well-formed answer. Upvoted.

Comment: Just to add to your answer about native v display res, the limiting factor in graphics performance can frequently be the pixel shaders that, as implied by their name, operate on every pixel.  In that scenario, having fewer pixels to operate on can and does make all the difference in how quickly the game can render a frame.

Comment: @SethBattin even when there weren't pixel shaders, drawing a line on the screen is afaik an O(n) operation, n being the number of pixels in the line. I don't know off the top of my head what the performance for triangle filling is, but I guess it's O(n) as well (except n is pixel "squared" here).

Comment: I've never seen games set to a resolution lower than the monitor's output video at the monitor's resolution. In my experience, they always output at the target resolution and the monitor upscales the image as necessary.

Comment: I have also seen vast FPS improvements by lowering the resolution in fullscreen mode in games.

Comment: @kotekzot It's obvious that having to render less pixels gives you better performance. However, when you do that in fullscreen mode, at least on Windows, as I said, you run into hefty additional performance losses whenever the game loses and regains focus.

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant the performance suffers during gameplay as well as switching to and from the game. Yes, it does seem a bit slower to switch to and from a fullscreen game running below your monitor's native resolution.

Comment: @badp Ah yes, and that "old" job is still happening of course.

Comment: What about "community services" such as Raptr and Steam? I swear I've seen a performance hit when they draw those notifications on top of the game in fullscreen that doesn't affect me in windowed mode.

Comment: You appear to be comparing apples to oranges *(running the game at higher resolution full-screen vs. lower-resolution windowed)*.  If you were to run that same game at a lower-than-desktop-resolution resolution but in full-screen, you'd likely get better performance than in windowed.

Comment: Also, except in rare instances, it's always the monitor that does the "scaling" from lower resolutions, not the GPU - that is why monitors have a list of supported resolutions.  And the "terrible performance/crashes when alt+tabbing" are completely dependent on the game and GPU driver being poorly coded; it was pretty common in the Windows 98 days, but but pretty rare now *(the notable exception being the Source engine)*.

Answer (score 20):

When an application runs in fullscreen mode, it runs in "exclusive mode". That means it has full and direct control over the screen output.

But when it runs in window mode, it needs to send its output to the window manager (windows explorer) which then manages where on the screen that output is drawn. This takes some additional performance. The performance penalty, however, is greatly reduced in newer version of windows.

Comment: Which newer version(s) of Windows?

Comment: When I switched from XP to 7 I found the performance tax on windowed 3d applications to be a lot lower. Most likely because the whole window manager is hardware-accelerated when using the Aero Glass user interface. I never used Vista so I don't know how the performance was there.

Comment: Starting with Vista.

Comment: Starting with Vista, when you have Aero turned on (you can't even turn it off anymore since 8).

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to make a quick addendum that could be useful for some players reading this topic: when recording gameplay, most applications can not retrieve frames from many games that are running in fullscreen mode.  Using windowed or windowed-fullscreen modes will usually provide full access to those frames, and is many times required for best results.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the other answers, in case of games like Oblivion, Fallout 3, Fallout: New Vegas and Skyrim, running in Windowed mode could help make the game more stable (prevent crashes) and reduce stuttering. Games like these also usually have issues with alt-tabbing, so running in Windowed mode will help.

Mods have been created to run these games in "Fake Fullscreen mode" (actually runs the game in Windowed mode, but makes it appear that it is fullscreen), e.g:

- [Fake Fullscreen Mode Windowed - Alt Tab Fix](http://oblivion.nexusmods.com/mods/38800) (Oblivion)
- [Fake Fullscreen Mode Windowed - Alt Tab Fix](http://newvegas.nexusmods.com/mods/41381) (Fallout 3 / Fallout: New Vegas)
- [Searching for 'Windowed' in Skyrim Nexus results in a bunch of mods that allow this for Skyrim](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/searchresults/?name=windowed&orderby=OLD_endorsements&sort=DESC)

Also, from this question: [How to force Maximized Fullscreen mode in any game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/17306/4797)

> I have seen several games that have a video display mode that is windowed with no borders, at the same resolution as the desktop. It's sometimes called "Borderless Windowed" mode, or "Maximized Fullscreen" mode. It seems to balance the trade-off between running in fullscreen, and running a game in windowed mode.
>
> #### Fullscreen vs Windowed
>
> A game in fullscreen mode fills your screen and is more immersive.
> Supposedly fullscreen mode provides better performance, but I don't
> anything about that (nor have I recently observed better performance
> in fullscreen mode). The most common caveat is that your computer
> chokes momentarily if you alt-tab to go do something else. Playing in
> windowed mode allows you to switch to other tasks with no delay, or
> even multitask. Windowed mode also seems to be better for users using
> dual displays.
>
> In Maximized Fullscreen mode, the game is in windowed mode, but the
> borders and title bar are removed and the resolution matches your
> desktop's. In effect, it looks like you're playing in fullscreen mode,
> but you can still switch to other applications with no delay. Sounds
> like the best of both worlds to me!
>
> [image]
>
> Multitasking is great if I happen to be respawning, waiting for a
> loading screen, or if I need to look up information about the game
> (like looking up quest info for MMOs). Clicking on the game pushes the
> other (naughty, immersion breaking) windows and the taskbar into the
> background, seamlessly filling the full screen.
>
> Unfortunately most games don't seem to include this feature yet.

Answer (score 2):

I don't for all of you, but when I play warframe  on my laptop in full screen I get like 28-30 fps on Max settings,  and when I play in windowed mode I get 53-60 fps on the same settings. And my laptop is a Toshiba satellite  Intel i-7  4 cores 2.4-3.4 (turbo boost)  ghz, 8g ram, video card Intel HD 4000

Answer (score 1):

General: Games in Fullscreen have better Performance, just because the explorer.exe of Windows can take a break. In window mode, it has to render the game and averything else you have open. But, if it is fullscreen, it renders everything from your desktop when you shift there. 
Specific: I have not experienced any improvement in a game when switching to window mode, the fps were going always down (testet with Counter Strike, World of Warcraft, Anno, Crysis, Starcraft, Diablo, Skyrim).

Comment: On the other hand, from personal experience games in fullscreen mode tend to be *terrible* at context switching when you need to alt-tab out for whatever reason. Windowed mode tends to be much more polite about it.

Comment: of course, but from the performance point oft view (which was the question) fullscreen is better.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this in League of Legends. I somewhat have an outdated PC and when I play LoL in fullscreen my fps were bound to 10-20 fps. I noticed a borderless option and for the heck of it, I tried it. Don't know how, but somehow it manages to stay above 50 fps. xD

Borderless all the way..

Answer (score 0):

Windowed is better in GTA V for me. A borderless window is faster than full screen and it's obvious immediately. When you mouse your view around your garage interior, even an empty garage, it's much smoother like you're really looking. When in full screen it jumps a bit, like it's sluggish and takes you out of the emersion (you don't want to see glitches in the matrix or you might realise it's not real).

Answer (score -1):

IDK if this is true, but when I was playing GTA V on ULTRA settings my GPU (GTX 770) (WINDOWED SCREEN) was on a higher temperature, 70/72C but when I was playing it in fullscreen mode it was 65C, so 65C was the maximum temperature however most of the time it was around 62/61C.

Those are just the Temperatures. but if it is Windowed or Fullscreen, I don't really see a big difference in FPS. (Personal Experience)

Answer (score -2):

For me personally, full screen and windowed screen have the same fps. But my PC tends to run cooler when i'm in windowed mode because it puts less stress on the PC.