# Noise with Minecraft in Fullscreen

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can hear an acute noise from my computer if I play Minecraft in Fullscreen or with a manually enlarged window. What may cause it?

OS: Windows 10 Pro 1511
CPU: i7-6700K
GPU: GTX 980Ti
Java: 1.8.0_66

Edit: I'm uploading a sample video.
I'll paste the link here:

watch this on a phone or something. I can't hear any difference on my pc, but I can clearly hear noise if watch this with a tablet or a phone with 100% volume

I have some news: setting a fixed amount of FPS solved any problem with the noise.. I was playing at 1000-2000FPS. Why I can't play with an unlimited framerate?

Comment: Are you running any mods?

Comment: just optifine..

Comment: Is it possible it could be the fan?

Comment: I use a Corsair H100i GTX

Comment: Not sure if this fits with the rules. @Studoku hey is this allowed?

Comment: Does this happen in any other games? Is the noise coming from speakers/headphones? Does limiting your FPS in options reduce the noise?

Comment: It comes from the CPU area inside the pc, it is not related to the monitor

Comment: If the noise appears when the GPU is under heavy load (like rendering many blocks in Minecraft) then I'm sure it's harmless but annoying coil whining. It should only happen at very high frame rates. I have/had? this problem with my GPU and it went away after some time, but in the beginning every benchmark with 500+ fps would cause coil whining.

Comment: Have you ever heard the noise coming from an AC-DC Adaptor? I'm talking about that kind of noise

Comment: Please don't edit the question without actual content (the video you mentioned) as this gets the question to the top of the main page and it shows a (1) on people who are waiting for a question to be asked (like me, lol).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that!

Comment: "It should only happen at very high frame rates. I have/had? this problem with my GPU and it went away after some time, but in the beginning every benchmark with 500+ fps would cause coil whining." -@GiantTree

Comment: Video in question is dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stated that it was gone after you limited your frames.

**It was likely caused by coil whining**, which usually is caused by very high frame rates.

If this happens to you or anyone else in the future, they can do what you did and **limit the frame rate/turn on V-sync**.​​​​​​

Comment: Well I think that this makes sense, but why this does not happen when game is in window mode?

Comment: @hiru you get less FPS in Windowed mode as other parts of the screen (taskbar, other apps etc.) get rendered too. [See the answers on this question too](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/107028/is-there-a-difference-between-running-games-in-windowed-or-fullscreen-mode)

Comment: Also hit the green tick *if this answer answered your question*.

Comment: So it is because of the amount of pixel rendered at a certain framerate and not a matter of only framerate, am I right?

Comment: @hiru think of your GPU as a drawing studio with millions of workers. You can get them to draw billions of dots every milliseconds, but as you make them bigger and more advanced pictures, they slow down, and if they don't slow down, they get so fast, that you can hear them scratching the picture.

Comment: @VoteToClose In the future, please don't fill suggested edits with whitespace just to make it happen.  If don't have enough of an edit to hit the minimum character limit, don't suggest it; add a comment.

Comment: @Frank Oh, alright. :D It was a one-letter fix, didn't really seem like that was worth bothering the poster about.

Comment: @VoteToClose "Fixed question/answer" etc

Comment: @VoteToClose There's a reason there's a minimum character limit; suggested edits add overhead as more people need to review to ensure the edit is good.  So if all you're doing is changing one letter, you're wasting other's time.

Comment: @Frank This is an _excellent_ point. `I'm an idiot`, I'll keep this in mind. Thanks.